# Why this string literal is assign-able to `keyof X` but cannot be used as key of 'X'?

Tags: typescript

I found an example where tsc-3.5.3 think statement

```js
let k : keyof typeof c = "value";
```

is legit, but statement

```js
c["value"]
```

is not.

I'm confused on why this could happen or what am I missing. Here is the full code snippet:

```js
type A = { keys: "value1" | "value2" };

<B extends A>() => {
    type C = { [ item in B["keys"] ] ?: any };
    let c : C = {};

    let k : keyof typeof c = "value1";
    // tsc think this is legit

    c[k]
    // also legit

    c["value1"]
    // tsc complains:
    // "Property 'value1' does not exist on type 'C'.ts(7053)"
};
```

Note that when I replace `"value1"` with `"valueX"`, like this:

```js
let k : keyof typeof c = "valueX";
```

tsc will then complain about `Type '"valueX"' is not assignable to type 'B["child"]'`.
In other words, tsc does aware that `"value1"` is a legit key of `c` while `"valueX"` is not.

Can someone help me understand how this could happen?

Thank you!

Comment: `B` can be type `{keys: "value2"}` (which extends `A`, since it is more specific) and then inside your function `value1` wouldn't be a known key of `c`.  Of course that means your `let k` could be incorrect, even though the compiler thinks it's okay.  I can't tell what's going on here, but it's weird.  Couldn't find a relevant GitHub issue addressing this, either.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! The inconsistency between `c[k]` vs `c["value1"]` still seems wired to me but your comment solved my original confusion.

Comment: I'm going to keep the question open as there maybe a reason for the inconsistency between `c[k]` v.s. `c["value1"]`, if that's the case I'm curious to know the reason.